# Property 'databaseName' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm trying to follow [highoncoding's tutorial](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/836_Persisting_iOS_Application_Data_in_SQLite_Database_Using_FMDB.aspx) in order to learn SQLite and using it with iOS programming.

When adding this line of code to my AppDelegate.m file:

```
self.databaseName = @"Customers.db";
```

I get the following error:

> Blockquote Property 'databaseName' not found on object of type 'AppDelegate *'

libsqlite3.dylib is in my frameworks folder.
What could be the problem?

Comment: A guess you didnt add ivar getter,setter. So basicly add '@property', '@syntesize' to your code.

Comment: oh... is databaseName just an added property? I thought it was some built-in thing :)

Comment: 'databaseName' isn't a part of AppDelegate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you synthesized the variable? It seems that the property is missing.

Comment: oh, i was not fast enough :(.

Answer (score 0):

Added @property and @syntesize for databaseName and it worked.